# Html CSS - div center, and left, right alignment

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do I make the top div of the full horizontal length of the main container, while keeping the next two div, `.left` and `.right` in flex to each other?

To look like this - [image]

```css
.main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.main div.top {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main div.left {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.main div.right {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="top">
      <h1>top</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="left">
      <h1>left</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
      <h1>right</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you willing to add more `div` to achieve this?
Or you want this behaviour while maintaining same number of elements

Comment: @UtsavPatel I am open to adding new div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

I just added 2 extra `div`s if that is not an issue?

```css
#MainDiv {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.main {
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#lower {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="MainDiv">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="top">
        <h1>top</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="lower">
        <div class="left">
          <h1>left</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
          <h1>right</h1>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is with grid:

```
.main  {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.main  .top {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
```

```css
.main  {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}

.main  .top {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

.main  .left {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.main .right {
  border: 1px solid green; 
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="top">   
    <h1>top</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="left">    
    <h1>left</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="right">    
    <h1>right</h1>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: flex;` and `flex-wrap: wrap` on the parent container, 100% width on the first child and `flex-grow: 1` on the other children, or also use percentage widths on the second and third DIVs.

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main  {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main  div.top {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  width:100%;
}

.main  div.left {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 40%;
}

.main div.right {
  border: 1px solid green; 
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class="main">
<div class="top">   <h1>top</h1>
   </div>
      
 <div class="left">    <h1>left</h1>
</div>

<div class="right">    <h1>right</h1>
</div>
     
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Any width of .left and .right

```css
.main {
      border: 1px solid red;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .main div.top {
      border: 1px solid orange;
      width: auto;
      display: inline-block;
      flex: 1 1 100%;
    }
    
    .main div.left {
      border: 1px solid blue;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
    
    .main div.right {
      border: 1px solid green;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="main">
      <div class="top">
        <h1>top</h1>
      </div>
  
      <div class="left">
        <h1>left 11111111</h1>
      </div>
  
      <div class="right">
        <h1>right</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can two `div` to create additional sections.

```css
.main  {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
flex-direction:column;
}

.main  div.top {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  width:auto; 
}

.main  div.left {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex:1
}

.main div.right {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex:1 
}
   .main__section2 {
display:flex
   }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="main__section1">
      <div class="top">
        <h1>top</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main__section2">
      <div class="left">
        <h1>left</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <h1>right</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```